# How many obtuse angle triangles are possible in a regular Heptagon by joining its vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, triangles, polygons

I am only able to make one possible case,

Where we take any 3-consecutive vertices, since one of the vertices contains angle of Heptagon, which is approximately 128.57°, we get 7 such triangles.

I am unable to any others cases where obtuse angle triangles are possible.

Comment: Label the vertices $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ (in order). So you have found $123$. What are the angles in $124$? You don't need to calculate them, just think what they would be in a hexagon ...

Answer (score 1):

Consider all the triangle with the center of the circle circumscribing heptagon lying inside it.
[image]

Take any vertex of the $△ABC$ (let's say we take vertex $A$)
If $∠A=α$ then $∠BOC=2α$
But $∠BOC < 180°$
⇒ $∠A<90°$ (as $A$ and  $O$ lie on the same side of  $BC$)
Similarly we can prove  $∠B<90°$  &  $∠C<90°$

Using the same logic we can prove  that the triangle is obtuse if $O$ lies outside the triangle.

Therefore for $△ABC$ to be obtuse the center O should lie outside the triangle.
There are only two non-congruent triangle satisfying the above property.
We can divide that into ***2 cases***  (as shown in figure).
[image]

$\underline{CASE-1} $
Let $C$ be the vertex containing the obtuse angle.
$C$ can take any of the seven vertices.
So there are total of $7$ possibilities in this case.

$\underline{CASE-2} $
Let $C$ be the vertex containing the obtuse angle.
There are two triangles with $C$ as vertex & $C$ can take any of the seven vertices.
So there are total of $7×2=14$ possibilities in this case.

Therefore, the total number obtuse triangles that can be drawn$=7+14=21$